# Remove span tag generate by checkbox

Tags: html, asp.net

How do I remove the span tag generated by the checkbox?

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox_select" type="checkbox" runat="server" onclick="javascript:CheckCheckBox(this);" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move to html input tag but with runat="server"

```
<input type="checkbox" id="CheckBoxSelect" runat="server" onclick="javascript:CheckCheckBox(this);" />
```

HTML server-side control

Comment: id="CheckBox_select" may not be valid remove underscore like  id="CheckboxSelect"

Answer (score 0):

You can use an input element:

```
<input id="CheckBox_select" type="checkbox" runat="server" onclick="javascript:CheckCheckBox(this);" />
```